# Show the datepicker of a DateElement on the same view in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: ios, datepicker, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, radioelement

I have a `DialogViewcontroller` in **Xamarin.IOS** and in this controller I have a `DateElement`. When clicking on the `DateElement`, the user is redirected to another view where he can select its date from a datepicker.
Now I want to show the datepicker on the same view of my `DialogViewcontroller`, just at the lower end of the view.
I have the same ambition with my `RadioElements`. I want to show the selectable options like this image to the user (show them as a picker on the same view):
[image]
How can I accomplish this?